# setCalorie in Dog model can not be applied to () ? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, spring

I am building a backend in Java for a Dog diet app and in the ServiceImplementation I am trying to save a new `Dog`. I have a model for dog which has a one to many relationship with `Calorie`. Calorie Model has fields for 10lb 20lb 30lb up to 100lb dog which the calories will vary based on weight.

I have a Many to One relationship Calorie with Dog and it is a array list so I am looping over the list and then I am doing if statements based on the dog == certain weight and then trying to `setcalories().gettenlb()` etc. And Intellij is not liking it for some reason and is giving me the error `setcalorie` can not be applied to ()

I don't know what's going on?

````
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "dogs")
    public class Dog {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long dogid;
    
        private int weight;
    
        private String name;
    
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "dog", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
        private Fat fat;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dog", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "dog",allowSetters = true)
        private List<Calorie> calorie = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "dog",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
        private Vegetable vegetable;
    
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "dog",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
        private Protein protein;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dog",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(value="dog",allowSetters = true)
        private List<Mineral> minerals = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dog", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "dog",allowSetters = true)
        private List<Vitamin>vitamins = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dog",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "dog",allowSetters = true)
        private List<AminoAcid> aminoacids = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dog",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "dog",allowSetters = true)
        private List<FattyAcid> fattyacids = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
        public Dog() {
        }
    
        public Dog(int weight, String name, Fat fat, Calorie calorie, Vegetable vegetable, Protein protein) {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.name = name;
            this.fat = fat;
            this.vegetable = vegetable;
            this.protein = protein;
        }
    
        public Long getDogid() {
            return dogid;
        }
    
        public void setDogid(Long dogid) {
            this.dogid = dogid;
        }
    
        public int getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }
    
        public void setWeight(int weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public Fat getFat() {
            return fat;
        }
    
        public void setFat(Fat fat) {
            this.fat = fat;
        }
    
        public void setDogid(long dogid) {
            this.dogid = dogid;
        }
    
      
    
        public Vegetable getVegetable() {
            return vegetable;
        }
    
        public void setVegetable(Vegetable vegetable) {
            this.vegetable = vegetable;
        }
    
        public Protein getProtein() {
            return protein;
        }
    
        public void setProtein(Protein protein) {
            this.protein = protein;
        }
    
        public List<Mineral> getMinerals() {
            return minerals;
        }
    
        public void setMinerals(List<Mineral> minerals) {
            this.minerals = minerals;
        }
    
        public List<Vitamin> getVitamins() {
            return vitamins;
        }
    
        public void setVitamins(List<Vitamin> vitamins) {
            this.vitamins = vitamins;
        }
    
        public List<AminoAcid> getAminoacids() {
            return aminoacids;
        }
    
        public void setAminoacids(List<AminoAcid> aminoacids) {
            this.aminoacids = aminoacids;
        }
    
        public List<FattyAcid> getFattyacids() {
            return fattyacids;
        }
    
        public void setFattyacids(List<FattyAcid> fattyacids) {
            this.fattyacids = fattyacids;
        }
    
        public List<Calorie> getCalorie() {
            return calorie;
        }
    
        public void setCalorie(List<Calorie> calorie) {
            this.calorie = calorie;
        }
    
    }
    
    ```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "calories")
    public class Calorie {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        private String tenlb;
    
        private String twentylb;
        private String thirtylb;
        private String fortylb;
        private String fiftylb;
        private String sixtylb;
        private String seventylb;
        private String eightylb;
        private String ninetylb;
        private String hundredlb;
    
        @ManyToOne()
        @JoinColumn(name = "dogid",nullable = false)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "calories",allowSetters = true)
        private Dog dog;
    
        public Calorie() {
        }
    
        public Calorie(String tenlb, String twentylb, String thirtylb, String fortylb, String fiftylb, String sixtylb, String seventylb, String eightylb, String ninetylb, String hundredlb, Dog dog) {
            this.tenlb = tenlb;
            this.twentylb = twentylb;
            this.thirtylb = thirtylb;
            this.fortylb = fortylb;
            this.fiftylb = fiftylb;
            this.sixtylb = sixtylb;
            this.seventylb = seventylb;
            this.eightylb = eightylb;
            this.ninetylb = ninetylb;
            this.hundredlb = hundredlb;
            this.dog = dog;
        }
    
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getTenlb() {
            return tenlb;
        }
    
        public void setTenlb(String tenlb) {
            this.tenlb = tenlb;
        }
    
        public String getTwentylb() {
            return twentylb;
        }
    
        public void setTwentylb(String twentylb) {
            this.twentylb = twentylb;
        }
    
        public String getThirtylb() {
            return thirtylb;
        }
    
        public void setThirtylb(String thirtylb) {
            this.thirtylb = thirtylb;
        }
    
        public String getFortylb() {
            return fortylb;
        }
    
        public void setFortylb(String fortylb) {
            this.fortylb = fortylb;
        }
    
        public String getFiftylb() {
            return fiftylb;
        }
    
        public void setFiftylb(String fiftylb) {
            this.fiftylb = fiftylb;
        }
    
        public String getSixtylb() {
            return sixtylb;
        }
    
        public void setSixtylb(String sixtylb) {
            this.sixtylb = sixtylb;
        }
    
        public String getSeventylb() {
            return seventylb;
        }
    
        public void setSeventylb(String seventylb) {
            this.seventylb = seventylb;
        }
    
        public String getEightylb() {
            return eightylb;
        }
    
        public void setEightylb(String eightylb) {
            this.eightylb = eightylb;
        }
    
        public String getNinetylb() {
            return ninetylb;
        }
    
        public void setNinetylb(String ninetylb) {
            this.ninetylb = ninetylb;
        }
    
        public String getHundredlb() {
            return hundredlb;
        }
    
        public void setHundredlb(String hundredlb) {
            this.hundredlb = hundredlb;
        }
    
        public Dog getDog() {
            return dog;
        }
    
        public void setDog(Dog dog) {
            this.dog = dog;
        }
    ```  public Dog save(Dog dog) {
            Dog newDog = new Dog();
            if (dog.getDogid() != 0) {
                dogrepos.findById(dog.getDogid())
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Dog Id" + dog.getDogid() + "not found"));
                newDog.setDogid(dog.getDogid());
            }
            newDog.setName(dog.getName());
            newDog.setWeight(dog.getWeight());
            newDog.setFat(dog.getFat());
            newDog.setProtein(dog.getProtein());
            newDog.setVegetable(dog.getVegetable());
    
            newDog.getAminoacids().clear();
            for (AminoAcid a : dog.getAminoacids()) {
                newDog.getAminoacids()
                        .add(new AminoAcid(a.getArginine(),
                                a.getHistidine(),
                                a.getIsoleucine(),
                                a.getLysine(),
                                a.getMethcysteine(),
                                a.getMethionine(),
                                a.getPhenaltyrosine(),
                                a.getThreonine(),
                                a.getTryptophan(),
                                a.getValine(),
                                a.getLeucine(), newDog));
            }
    
            for (Calorie c : dog.getCalorie()) {
                if (dog.getWeight() == 10) {
                    newDog.setCalorie().getTenlb();
    
                }
                if (newDog.getWeight() == 20) {
                    newDog.setCalorie().getTwentylb();
    
                }
                if (newDog.getWeight() == 30) {
                    newDog.getCalorie()
    
                }
                if (newDog.getWeight() == 40) {
                    newDog.setCalorie(getFortylb());
                }
            }
            if (newDog.getWeight() == 50) {
                newDog.setCalorie().getFiftylb();
            }
            if (newDog.getWeight() == 60) {
                newDog.setCalorie().getSixtylb();
            }
            if (newDog.getWeight() == 70) {
                newDog.setCalorie().getSeventylb();
            }
            if (newDog.getWeight() == 80) {
                newDog.setCalorie().getEightylb();
            }
            if (newDog.getWeight() == 90) {
                newDog.setCalorie().getNinetylb()
            } if (newDog.getWeight() == 100) {
                newDog.setCalorie().getHundredlb();
            }
````

Answer (score 0):

`setcalories()` is a method with a void return type.
If you want to chain call the `Callories` that you set in the field, you should change the return type.